# Проблема подгрузки картинок в слайдере!

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

У нас есть кнопка 'Click' , когда нажимаем открывается модальное окно , в модальном окне у нас есть слайдер pgwslider(http://pgwjs.com/pgwslider/), проблема в том что картинки слайдера не подгружаются , но если кликнуть  "исследовать элемент" то картинки сразу загружаются и слайдер работает на ура!

```css
#Modal{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#Modal" id="JS-Open">Click</a>
<div id="Modal">
<ul class="pgwSlider">
               <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="Slide1"></li>
               <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Slide2"></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня указан и альт и src в примере просто нету!

Comment: добавьте [mcve]

Comment: вы попробуйте на всяк случай `.pgwSlider();` при показе модального окна делать, а не при загрузке страницы, или как у вас?

Comment: или `.reload` вызвать, к примеру

Comment: reload не помогает даже если указать параметр maxHeight